# How to get latest tweet from Twitter?

Tags: iphone, ipad, twitter, ios-simulator

I have tried to get the latest Tweet from twitter using below Link.

http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/public_timeline.json

But that's not working. SO please guide me how to get latest Tweets.

Comment: Did you authenticate before sending this request? As of API v1.1, every request needs to be authenticated and did you make sure that the API endpoint is still active?

Comment: Yes i authenticated before sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `statuses/public_timeline.json` API endpoint has been removed in October last year, so its not included in the API v1.1.

The [Twitter Dev Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline) recommend using the endpoint `statuses/sample.json` instead. See  [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/sample) for the API Spec.

Comment: Now I get the Tweet using MGTwitterEngine(http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/) using this link but now i can get only first 20 tweets.

Comment: The Docs are a bit vague there, saying that you get a "small random sample of public tweets". I don't think its possible to specify a number (with the statuses/sample endpoint) so the API returns the n-latest tweets. I would think, that, if you need more, you need to send another request or something.

Comment: Hey Hi Do you know How to Authenticate using Twitter Framework..?

Comment: @iTejas http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios are good resources to get started